# Hypothesis testing for vector of order statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, order-statistics

I have a process that generates `n` values and returns the `k` largest. I would like to test if the results my process generates are stronger (bigger is better) than another process (call it the null process) that generates values in a similar way, generating `n` and returning the `k` largest.

**Are there any standard procedures designed to test this type of hypothesis?**

Other information: My first thought was to take the sum of the `k` order statistics and just do standard hypothesis testing on that, but the sum isn't necessarily of interest.
The `n` values generated by the null process appear to be normally distributed, if that influences anything. Also, I can make the assumption that they behave independently, even though they are certainly not independent.

Comment: please give more details and data. define k and k-largest and null process too.